# Please explain this proof to me on convex analysis: what does it mean to be bounded here?

Tags: convex-analysis, proof-explanation, finance

This is a problem from financial mathematics. I have never studied convex analysis, but it is apparently needed in this proof, which I am having trouble to understand.

Firstly, $M$ is a matrix, $v$ is a vector. Define the set $\{Mx  | x \cdot v \le 0\}$. So, it is the set of all vectors $Mx$ such that the dot product of each $x$ with $v$ is nonpositive. Note that all vectors involved here have appropiate dimensions so the products all make sense.

I need to show that if this set is unbounded, the following condition is *not* satisfied.

**Condition:** There is no $x$ with $x \cdot v\le 0$ such that every element of $Mx$ is nonnegative and at least one is strictly positive.

Firstly, what does it mean that it is bounded, when we're talking a set of vectors? Is it element-wise bounded? Bounded norm? What?

Secondly, how do we show that if the set is unbounded, the condition is not satisfied? The proof I am reading just says:

> the set is convex, and so if it is unbounded, there must exist an associative ray which is infinitely long, and therefore the condition is not satisfied.

I understand little of that. Why must there exist an "associative ray"? What actually is it? Why is it infinitely long? In which *direction* is it infinitely long? And why does its existence prove the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: What does "every element of $Mx$" mean? If $x$ is a vector, isn't $Mx$ also a vector?

Comment: Yes. A vector consists of elements.